# C++ help regarding class implementation and writing into a created text file

Tags: c++, class, header, fstream, cstring

I have been confused for a few hours on how I should fix this.. I have two functions in my implementation file for my class. Anyways, I've been trying to get my program to scramble words in this certain file I have on my computer (which is a dictionary list of many words), which so far has been successful.

But, the problem is that I'm trying to bring all of scrambled version of the words onto a newly created text document that stores them... So far, it hasn't been working and I'm really confused. I bolded where the problem is in the code.

Please note: I'm a student who's currently learning C++ and the code is a little unorganized until I can finish the general core of the program. My instructor says I am not allowed to use the string class, **ONLY cstring.**

Area that needs help:

**"cout << tmpword << endl; //What I want written into my new text file **** HELP"**
and
"new_dictionary<

Thanks in advance!

```
void Scrambler::scrambleletters_in_file()
{
    char * tmpword = nullptr;  //NULL

    // compare with every single word in the dictionary
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionarySize; i++)
    {
        // clean the space holding the previous word if any
        if (tmpword != nullptr)
            delete[] tmpword;

        //prepare space
        tmpword = new char[strlen(dictionary[i]) + 1];
        strcpy_s(tmpword, strlen(dictionary[i]) + 1, dictionary[i]);

// do the unscrambling stuff here

        // 1 2 3 4 5 6  7
        int first = 1; // H I C K E N '/0'
        int last = strlen(tmpword) - 2; // = C H I C K E 

        // We are showing the difference here, where the first/last letters are
        // not scrambled.

        for (int i = first; i < last; i++)
        {

            int j = rand() % last + 1; // Chicken[1-5]'s letters will be randomized
            // For instance: "hicke" will be scrambled.

            char result = tmpword[i];
            tmpword[i] = tmpword[j];
            tmpword[j] = result;
        }

        cout << tmpword << endl; //What I want written into my new text file **** HELP

    }


}

void Scrambler::createNew_dictionary()
{

    // ofstream is used for writing files
    // We'll make a file called scrambled_words.txt
    char newfilename[25];

    char choice3;

    cout << "\nHow do you want to create the new scrambled file? (Input 1 or 2) " << endl;
    cout << " - PRESET: (\"unscrambled_file.txt\"):  1 " << endl;
    cout << " - CUSTOM:\t\t\t      2 " << endl;
    cout << "\nChoice ===> ";
    cin >> choice3;


    if (choice3 == '1')
    {

        strcpy_s(newfilename, 25, "unscrambled_file.txt"); // copies the preset filename into "newfilename"

    }

    if (choice3 == '2')
    {

        cout << "\nWhat would you like the new file name to be? (EXAMPLE: \"test.txt\")" << endl;
        cout << "~ Note: if you type in an already existing file name, it will be overwritten " << endl;
        cout << "* WARNING: USE underscores INSTEAD of spaces in the text file name! " << endl; // Since I'm supposed to use cstring
        // instead of string, this won't work with spaces
        cout << "\nFile Name ====> ";
        cin >> newfilename; // ^ Practing by adding user input customization ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

//*TO DO (and practice) - SHOW A LIST OF CURRENTLY EXISTING .txt FILES, AND SELECT A FILE TO DELETE//
    }

    ofstream new_dictionary(newfilename); // Opens and/or creates the specified file if it hasn't already.

    // If we couldn't open the output file stream for writing
    if (!new_dictionary)
    {
        // Print an error and exit
        cout << "Uh oh, the text file could not be opened for writing!" << endl;
        system("PAUSE"); // this is just included so you have time to read what the error message
                         // says before the program is exited by the next statement.

        exit(1); // equivilent to "return 0;" in main function
    }

    else
        cout << "File successfully created and opened" << endl;

    new_dictionary<<scrambleletters_in_file(); // <--- MY PROBLEM ********

    /* We'll write two lines into this file
    new_dictionary << "This is line 1" << endl;
    new_dictionary << "This is line 2" << endl;
    */

    cout << "File successfully overwritten" << endl;

    new_dictionary.close();
    cout << "File closed. " << endl;

}
```

Comment: Please use `std::string` and other C++ classes. Don't write C when you don't have to.

Comment: @o11c I have to though. My professor said we shouldn't be using string yet.

Comment: then ignore them and DO IT RIGHT. There is literally nothing to be learned from avoiding it, and in this field you *need* to get into the habit of ignoring people who hold blatantly untrue opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `scrambleletters_in_file()` you are outputting strings to `cout` which is standard output (console by default). This line:

```
new_dictionary<<scrambleletters_in_file();
```

means "calculate the result of function `scrambleletters_in_file` and write it to `new_dictionary`". And its result is `void`, so the code doesn't even compile.

What you need is to pass the stream to the function:

```
void Scrambler::scrambleletters_in_file(ostream& out) {
    ...
    out << tmpword << endl;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
scrambleletters_in_file(new_dictionary);
```